# Bold and Unbolding the text in a cell in an Objective-C NSTableView with code

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This sounds basic, but then again it may not be.  I have some text in a cell that I want to go bold when an event happens and unbold when another happens, I know how to handle the event, but how do I make it bold and then unbold it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make text bold is specific range:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *theText = [theTextView textStorage];
[theText applyFontTraits:NSBoldFontMask range:NSMakeRange(0,[text length])];
```

Optionally how to get the selected range:

```
NSRange theSelectedRange = [theTextView selectedRange];
```